# Is it possible to create a google-assistant where all the data is stored in the EU? (DSGVO?)

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I work for a company based in germany and we already released an "assistant-app" but because of some EU Data-Security restrictions and such we have to store the data from the assistant app somewhere in europe.

Is it possible to create (for example) a new aog project and specify that it has to be EU hosted?
Does anyone have another idea?
The german "Datenschutzgrundverordnung" is really "special" ;)

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can contact Google's partner team for more details and try the enterprise account. For storing data in the database, you could use GCP's cloud data store and set it for the EU region. Firebase on the other side will make copies around the world as per my knowledge so that you should avoid.
Reach out to Dialogflow and ActionOnGoogle teams for the exact solution.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'll contact the support directly. If I get any other news I will post them here.